# Why do I get an error when using a print function with Python iter?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

When I use `print(list(my_iter))` in code before printing, it throws an error:

```
a = [4, 7, 0, 3]
my_iter = iter(a)
print(list(my_iter))

print(my_iter.__next__())
print(my_iter.__next__())

>StopIteration
```

but if I comment it, it runs fine. Why?

```
a = [4, 7, 0, 3]
my_iter = iter(a)
# print(list(my_iter))

print(my_iter.__next__())
print(my_iter.__next__())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A python `iter` can only be traversed once. By calling it as a list, you've 'used it up' - you must initialise it again if you wish to call `__next__`, since you've reached the end.

You can read more about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp).